# python 3.6 sum of the short periods between timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing some work with logs. Need to calculate a sum of time duration when the process was running without long interruptions. Set the maximum possible interruption to 30 seconds. Logs are emitted every 3 seconds.

So, **for example** if it was running since `10:20:00` (hours) to `10:30:00` and was interrupted from `10:24:10` to `10:27:10`, the desired result is the sum of `10:24:10` - `10:20:00` and `10:30:00` - `10:27:10` = `420` (in seconds). However, calculating time difference using `datetime` types does not provide a valid solution - I suppose it calculates a difference without including a start/end seconds.

**here is the solution I came up with** (['timestamps'] is a list of `datetime` timestamps normally emitted every 3 sec):

```
for k, v in proc_activity.items():
        proc_activity[k]['duration'] = 0

        start, next = v['timestamps'][0], ''
        for time in v['timestamps']:
            next = time
            diff = next - start

            if diff.seconds < 30:
                proc_activity[k]['duration'] += diff.seconds
            else:
                print("diff: %s" % diff.seconds)

            start = next

        print(f"added: {proc_activity[k]['duration']}")
        diff = v['timestamps'][-1] - v['timestamps'][0]
        print(f"real: {diff.seconds}")
```

**output:**

```
added: 39
real: 45
added: 39
real: 45
diff: 36
added: 155
real: 218
```

any suggestion how to fix it?

***update, sample input data:***

```
{'service_0': {'timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 39, 86170),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 42, 33213),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 44, 898234),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 47, 893731),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 50, 928946),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 53, 895617),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 7, 116182),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 10, 105035),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 13, 193428),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 16, 210135),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 19, 168881),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 22, 114653),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 25, 102365),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 43, 46950),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 46, 15435),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 49, 23333),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 52, 22164),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 55, 78615),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 58, 78573)]}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, I think the key thing you are missing is to use `timedelta.total_seconds()` rather than `timedelta.seconds`

This seems to work fine for me:

```
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

def get_duration(timestamps):
    max_interruption = 30
    starts = timestamps[:-1]
    ends = timestamps[1:]
    durations = zip(starts, ends)
    accumulated = 0
    for start, end in durations:
        delta = (end - start).total_seconds()
        if delta < max_interruption:
            accumulated += delta
    return accumulated

proc_activity = {
    'service_0': {
        'timestamps': [
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 39, 86170),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 42, 33213),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 44, 898234),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 47, 893731),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 50, 928946),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 53, 895617),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 7, 116182),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 10, 105035),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 13, 193428),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 16, 210135),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 19, 168881),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 22, 114653),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 25, 102365),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 43, 46950),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 46, 15435),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 49, 23333),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 52, 22164),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 55, 78615),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 58, 78573)
        ],
    }
}

for k,v in proc_activity.items():
    proc_activity[k]['duration'] = get_duration(v['timestamps'])

pprint(proc_activity)
```

has a duration of `65.77183800000002` seconds

Comment: Hi, isn't this almost the same as my solution? i suppose the issue is because `diff = next - start` do not include `<=`, `=>` when calculating difference. or something like that. i'll provide a sample in 5 minutes.

Comment: The solution itself isn't much different from mine, but yeah this was the point `.total_seconds()`

Answer (score 3):

My try to the problem using generators:

```
import datetime

def calculate(timestamps, largest_interrupt = 30):
    begin_t, last_good_t = timestamps[0], timestamps[0]
    for current_t, previous_t in zip(timestamps[1:], timestamps):
        if (current_t - last_good_t).total_seconds() < largest_interrupt:
            last_good_t = current_t
            continue
        yield (previous_t - begin_t).total_seconds()
        last_good_t, begin_t = current_t, current_t
    yield (current_t - begin_t).total_seconds()

sample_data = {'service_0': {'timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 39, 86170),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 42, 33213),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 44, 898234),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 47, 893731),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 50, 928946),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 33, 53, 895617),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 7, 116182),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 10, 105035),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 13, 193428),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 16, 210135),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 19, 168881),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 22, 114653),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 25, 102365),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 43, 46950),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 46, 15435),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 49, 23333),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 52, 22164),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 55, 78615),
                                     datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 22, 35, 58, 78573)]}}


for k, v in sample_data.items():
    s = sum(calculate(v['timestamps']))
    print(f"Service '{k}' has duration of '{s}' seconds")
```

The program prints `Service 'service_0' has duration of '65.771838' seconds`